# How to get multiple textbox id in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I want to get multiple textbox id in document.ready(function).

I tried to get it but it is not working.

How is it possible using comma separator or other way..?

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
    $(".Table-right .MinValue, .Carat-right .MinValue,.Price-right .MinValue,.Depth-right .MinValue ").attr('id');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  var output = $(".Table-right .MinValue, .Carat-right .MinValue,.Price-right .MinValue,.Depth-right .MinValue ");

  
  output.each(function(index) {

    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).attr('id'));
  });


});
```

```html
Not Sure if this is what you are going for but if this is how you set up your data than you did it correctly.


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Table-right">
  <input type="text" class="MinValue" id="test1">

</div>

<div class="Carat-right">
  <input type="text" class="MinValue" id="test2">

</div>

<div class="Price-right">
  <input type="text" class="MinValue" id="test3">

</div>

<div class="Depth-right">
  <input type="text" class="MinValue" id="test4">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector gives a `nodelist`. So you have to Iterate over them to fetch the individual `id` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $(".Table-right .MinValue, .Carat-right .MinValue,.Price-right .MinValue,.Depth-right .MinValue ").each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr(id))
});
})
```